# is the configure block needed?

Tags: node.js

i'm starting to use Express Web Framework, at the moment i'm not using any configure block, like this:

```
app.configure(function(){

   app.use(express.logger);

});
```

but i write al the middleware directly:

```
app.use(express.favicon);
app.use(express.logger);
```

etc etc

Is it wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `configure`.

That method is provided as a useful way to group configuration in one spot. Think about it in the context of having different modes of operation, such as development vs. production.